If everyone keeps their previous lives memories, why do people behave the same at the beginning of every cycle in the Endless?
In the movie, the Endless, characters are trapped in time-domes set up by a Lovecraftian elder god. According to their narration, they do keep their memories of previous lives they have lived many times before.
If this is the case, why do some of them still behave as if they were experiencing their current life as a fresh new experience?
One outstanding example is the two characters (Michael and Chris) who are trapped in a remote house, (they are from a different movie by the same directors, the movie is Resolution); after Michael sets their house ablaze defiantly, their time-dome is reset; Michael comes up from behind a car waving at Chris, who is holding a gun, yelling something like "Do not shoot, it is your friend" and Chris recoganises Michael in joy.
Why do Michael and Chris behave this way after perhaps thousands of resets of their time-domes? If they indeed keep their previous memories, they would have behaved differently, no?

After watching Resolution again, I think I know why.
The Lovecraftian elder god wants to toy with Michael and Chris, by leaving them with tapes and other clues as well as trapping them in a time-dome.
The only way Michael and Chris see out of this entrapment is to satisfy this elder god; hence Michael and Chris, despite of possessing previous memories, have to play along with the script written by this elder god.
